# How to prevent Laravel event() from firing during unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a class that uses Laravel's global event() function to fire off a single event when a model is changed. The only way I have been able to prevent this event from firing during unit tests is to actually namespace and declare a new event() function in the test itself and make it do nothing. It works, but it doesn't seem like a pretty solution to me. I looked into the Laravel docs and I can see some people have used Event::fake() inside the test successfully, but when I try to do it I get:

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0_Illuminate_Contracts_Events_Dispatcher::until() does not exist on this mock object
```

I'm on Laravel 5.4. Is there a cleaner way to prevent this event from firing during a test? I really dislike the idea of declaring an empty namespaced event() function.

EDIT:

The class I am testing is a UserDomain class. In one part of the logic it invokes Laravel's global event() method:

```
event(new RoleChanged($this->user));
```

To suppress this from firing in a test I have tried Event::fake() and I have also tried using the trait WithoutEvents and its withoutEvents() method. Neither work, and the same error I mentioned above occurs both times.

Comment: show what you attempted to use that is causing the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read some more docs on mocking in Laravel unit testing and I discovered that all I had to do is this at the beginning of the test:

```
$this->expectsEvents(RoleChanged::class);
```

This tells framework to acknowledge this event occurred but to not actually fire it off. Thanks everybody for your help. It led me to a workable solution.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutEvents` trait in your test.

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutEvents;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutEvents;
}
```

Comment: I tried that. It still returned the same error. I will add some more info to the original question.

Comment: @JoelJoelBinks Since I don't know what you're doing actually, I can't give you the exact answer. But, my answer is the correct way to stop event from firing. I think you're mocking the events or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For whatever reason the WithoutEvents solution did not work for me, but the expectsEvents() method below in my answer did. Go figure.

Comment: @JoelJoelBinks Wut? Why you're accepting my answer? 

Comment: Whoops :) sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutEvents` trait, and place `$this->withoutEvents()` before any test.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutEvents;

class UsersTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutEvents;
    
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function email_is_required()
    {
         $this->withoutEvents();
         // assertions
    }

}
```